# How to remove an object from a list collection?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I had to change on my lines of code around. I before had something like this

```
// this is in a static method.
List<string> mySTring = new List<string>();

mySTring.add("one");
mySTring.add("two");
```

However on one of my pages I have a dropdownlist that does not require the field "two" so instead of writing duplicate code all I did was

```
myString.remove("two");
```

Now I need to change my list to a `List<SelectListItem> myList = new List<SelectListItem>();`

So I have it now looking like this:

```
  List<SelectListItem> myList = new List<SelectListItem>()
            { 
                new SelectListItem() { Text = "one", Value = "one"},
                new SelectListItem() { Text = "two", Value = "two"},
            };
```

So now how do I remove the selectListItem that contains "two"? I know I probably could use remove by index. But I might add to list in the future so I don't want to start hunting down and changing it if the index changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`List<T>` is, by default, going to be comparing object references (unless `SelectListItem` implements a custom equality method). So unless you still have a reference to the second item around, you are going to have to get it either by reference, or by **finding** the desired item:

```
var item = myList.First(x=>x.Value == "two");
myList.Remove(item);
```

Index may be easier...

Comment: hmm was hoping to now have to search for it. I won't have the reference anymore, I guess I will make remove by index or by finding. Not sure what to use. Just concerned in the future I add something to my list collection and all of a sudden it is a different index and I am trying to figure out why it is not wokring and that is the reason.

Comment: Also how would the List collection sort method work on this? Because I was using the sort method on my list of strings(thats why I am concerned the index will change).

Comment: Well, you could always use a different container that doesn't require searching by brute force.

Comment: `List<T>`'s sorting works on standard sorting; it depends whether `SelectListItem` implements `IComparable` or `IComparable<SelectListItem>`.

Comment: my list does not give me an option for "First" does certain list object not get it?

Comment: Hmm the sort method does not work either. So any ideas on how to sort it?

Comment: The First method shown is LINQ, which should be available since you are using MVC. Try adding "`using System.Linq;`" to the top of that file. Sort is tricky since there is no inbuilt method that will work on the **words**.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [RemovalAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) method:

```
myList.RemoveAll(i => i.Text == "two");
```

Obviously this will get rid of *all* the items whose "Text" property is "two", but since you're using it in a ComboBox I'm assuming you'll only have one item for each "Text" value.

Answer (score 0):

we can make mouse selection over the autocomplete div by adding this following code

into the jquery autocomplete function

here i have used the id name as Requiredid

```
 $("#Requiredid").autocomplete({focus:function(e,ui) {
      document.getElementById('Requiredid').value = ui.item.label;
      document.getElementById('hdnValue').value = ui.item.id;//If You need this value you //can add this line
}});
```