# LINQ Invalid arguments for Collections.Generic.List.RemoveAll

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have this method which is telling me I have some invalid arguments where I'm trying to call `RemoveAll` from my `List<SelectListItem>` object. I simply just need to remove a few items from a dropdown list based upon a simple condition.

```
public JsonResult GetExportTables(CaseListDynExport objCaseListDynExport)
{
    List<SelectListItem> lstExportTablesList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    try
    {
        CaseListDynExportBLL objCaseListDynExportBLL = new CaseListDynExportBLL();

        DataTable dtExportTables = objCaseListDynExportBLL.GetExportTables(objCaseListDynExport);

        lstExportTablesList = DropDownHelper.GetSelectListItem("TableName", "TableExportCode", null, dtExportTables);

        if (objCaseListDynExport.someCondition)
            lstExportTablesList.RemoveAll(lstExportTablesList.Where(l => l.Text.IndexOf("Audit") >= 0));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogUtility.ErrorException(ex);
    }

    return Json(lstExportTablesList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I must be missing something really obvious, but I can't spot what I'm doing wrong.

I've looked at these posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1698166/1189566
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874550/1189566
- https://www.dotnetperls.com/removeall
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx

But yea; can't spot what I'm doing incorrectly...

Comment: You're missing the fact, that `RemoveAll` takes not a list, but `Predicate` as argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
lstExportTablesList.RemoveAll(l => l.Text.IndexOf("Audit") >= 0);
```

So you pass a lambda method directly to the `RemoveAll` method for checking the condition.

A neater way, with the same functionality, would be:

```
lstExportTablesList.RemoveAll(l => l.Text.Contains("Audit"));
```

Comment: Ugh, thanks. I was looking at the `Remove` example where it had `lst.Where` in the argument then didn't notice the difference for the other calls... one of those days :(

Comment: I will when I can in 8 minutes ;)

Comment: I didn't know there was a time delay :) 15 minutes I see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer .